# Add data to post edit page, when post is published

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How do I add some custom PHP to the "post edit"-page, and get the `post_id`, when the post is published?

**Like this red area:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `get_current_screen()` function ([Link to codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen)) to check that you're on a post edit page and then get post id with a global `$post` variable.

Example:

```
add_action('admin_notices', 'screen_info');
function screen_info() {
  $screen = get_current_screen();
  if(is_admin() && $screen->id == 'post') {
    global $post;
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    // your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I found out that I could use the `add_meta_box`, which works as intended. But thanks anyway! Have a nice weekend.